# Rebuild canceled because of .mdf growth

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the Standard Edition of SQL Server 2012 and used a script to rebuild an index. I ran the query and then I saw that the `.mdf` file for the database started the grow a lot.

I chose to cancel/stop my query that run the rebuild of the database.

I checked in database what happened with the following queries:

```
SP_who2

select cmd,* 
from sys.sysprocesses
where blocked > 0
```

I saw that a process where blocked so I chose to kill that one.

The query/spid became marked with cancel/roolback in `SP_who2`.

It took a lot of time to rollback the query.

The table that was rebuilding was a big with over 4 million rows and a fragmentation of 99%.

My questions are:

1. Why did the `.mdf` grow that fast? About 1 gb/(10/sec)
2. When I stopped my query, can the database get inconsistent in any way?
3. Can the data in the database have been changed because of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this doesn't feel related to programming.

Comment: It's the maintenance of databases...where will I ask that then?

Comment: probably http://dba.stackexchange.com/